# Returning PNG with Django 1.7

Tags: python, django, png, mime-types, content-type

Since Django 1.7 seems to no longer support mimetype (replaced by content_type?), I have following error:

```
__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'mimetype'
```

...while trying to execute:

```
import qrcode

def generate_qrcode(request):
    img = qrcode.make("some string")
    response = HttpResponse(mimetype="image/png")
    img.save(response, "PNG")
    return response
```

This code was working fine before (django 1.6). Any idea how to return a PNG with Django 1.7?

Many thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

So easy to find.... Just replaced "mimetype" with "content_type" :)

```
def generate_qrcode(request):
    img = qrcode.make("some string")
    response = HttpResponse(content_type="image/png")
    img.save(response, "PNG")
    return response
```